# Is there any cleaner way to check if a Type is integral?

Tags: c#, types

Currently the code we can write to check this is just by listing all possible types for the so-called `integral`, like this:

```
public static bool IsIntegral(this Type type)
{
        return type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(uint) ||
               type == typeof(short) || type == typeof(ushort) ||
               type == typeof(long) || type == typeof(ulong) ||
               type == typeof(byte);
}
```

I wonder if there is some better and cleaner way that should not involve any trick with converting to/from string (that I think will not perform well, even we have to create some dummy instance from Type using `Activator`).

It's a pity that something like this would not work:

```
typeof(long).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

Whereas actually in code we can write something like this:

```
int i = 5;
long l = i;//this looks much like long can be assignable from int
```

But actually they (long and int) don't have any inheritance relationship here, the compiler seems to do some magic auto-casting here for the above code to be valid.

Comment: What do you need to use this check for? Should it ever accept user-defined types?

Comment: Ugh, it's been a very long day for me, I should really go home! Anyway, I don't think there is a shorter way, perhaps if we had more context, we could suggest something better.

Comment: I feel like this is an XY question.

Comment: @Ry- I want to use this to check if a key property type is integer to apply a correct mapping (such as set it as identity instead of a non-identity). It involves column mapping here (between entity key properties and primary columns). The example implementation is just fairly long and I just wonder if there is any better cleaner way (not so important).

Comment: you could `switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))` ? but: you'd still have to hard-code the options you like

Comment: [TypeCode Enum Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Does it strike you as odd that `byte` is on that list but `sbyte` is not? You've got the unsigned and signed versions of 2, 4 and 8 byte integers, and only the unsigned one-byte integer.

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you, looks like your suggestion opens a shorter/cleaner way :)

Comment: You express a performance concern without stating what your performance budget is. How many such operations per second do you require be performed? There are many ways to optimize this sort of code, but if it is already a thousand times faster than it needs to be, who cares if we can make it faster?

Comment: @EricLippert yes, actually `sbyte` is not added there because I did not think it should be the case (even byte is rarely the case), as I commented above about the use case of column mapping (usually `int` and `long` are the most types used).

Comment: If you are concerned about performance and if int and long are the most common, then why are you not checking them first?  Why do you spend all the time -- several entire nanoseconds! -- checking for `uint`, `short` and `ushort` before `long` if that almost never happens? Can you explain what performance testing process you are using?

Comment: @EricLippert really I did not think much about performance issue, it's just kind of constraint to make this question become harder and more interesting :). As I already commented before, finding a better/cleaner way is also not really important because I can always use the code I posted which should work just fine.

Comment: Please don't ask questions that you don't care about the answers to. That wastes the time of the people who are trying to help you solve real engineering problems. If you care about performance, use good engineering practice and *test your performance*.

Comment: @EricLippert sorry about that, anyway the curiosity about a better way is good to learn more. As Marc Gravell suggested, I think that way is at least neater (and I've learnt one thing new from his suggestion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation raised from suggestion of @Marc Gravell, about using `Type.GetTypeCode`, interestingly that the code range from `sbyte` to `uint64` is continuous from `5` to `12` (as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netframework-4.8). So assume that they are not changed (and actually they should not), we can have the following neater code:

```
public static bool IsIntegral(this Type type)
{
    var typeCode = (int) Type.GetTypeCode(type);
    return typeCode > 4 && typeCode < 13;
}
```

Thank you for the downvotes, but I've learnt something new here :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be much better, but seems easier to change if needed:

```
private static readonly Type[] integralTypes = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(uint), 
                                                       typeof(short), typeof(ushort),
                                                       typeof(long), typeof(ulong), 
                                                       typeof(byte) };

public static bool IsIntegral(this Type type)
{
    return integralTypes.Contains(type);
}
```

Comment: well I don't think this could save me any typing compared with my original code :( , thank you anyway.

Answer (score -4):

How about you try `Int64.TryParse(value)` Successful conversion means its an integral value. You will have to exclude bool and string though.
You could also play with `IsNumber` but again you would have to account for string values.

Given that, I guess the best bet is to write a helper method to check that based on possible combinations.

Comment: I was confused why you got downvoted, but I think that they want to pass in a `type` and not a `value`

Comment: `Int64.TryParse` only takes a string. Are you thinking of something else?